# MongoDB $groupby $addToSet all possible items

Tags: mongodb

I want to group my Songs collection by artist_name, and retrieve all possile fields of a Songs element in a "songs" field. What expression should I use ?

```
{
        "$group":
        {
            "_id": "$artist_name",
            "songs" : { "$addToSet" : <expression for all song fields?> }
        }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to push the $$Root:

```
const songs = await Songs.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
     // match conditions here
    },
  },
  { $group: { _id: '$artist_name', songs: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
]);
```

Comment: So fast ! thank you so much that's exactly what I needed